# How to selectively bypass TUN OpenVPN client for VNC service?

Tags: macos, router, openvpn, vnc

I have a Mac Mini connected to internet via an ASUS router running ASUS's modified WRT firmware. All devices have latest software/firmware.

The Mini does scheduled connections to the internet via a TUN OpenVPN Client running on the Mini.

The OpenVPN client is configured to route "all" over the VPN, but has some common-sense exceptions for local network traffic.

- When the Mini is **NOT** connected via OpenVPN, I can connect to it
  locally and remotely by Apple's VNC-based Desktop Sharing. (Remote
  connections use port forwarding through the ASUS gateway router.)
- When the Mini **is** connected via OpenVPN, I can connect to it as
  usual on the local network, and connect to it by connecting to the
  "far" end of the VPN tunnel.
- However, when the VPN is *up* I cannot remotely connect to the Mini
  by using the ASUS WAN address+port forwarding that works
  otherwise.

**Problem:**

- Because connections through the far end of the tunnel are slow and
  awkward, I would like to be able to remotely connect to the Mini via
  my ASUS's WAN address even when the VPN tunnel is up.

**Question:**
How would I go about solving this problem in a simple way?

- I am willing to add modest additional hardware (such as more
  Ethernet ports and/or routers) to accomplish this, particularly if
  doing so avoids a potentially fragile software solution, but a
  software/configuration solution is OK.
- Extra points for a solution that works whether or not the tunnel is
  up.